# How to highlight or draw line on where 2 or more meshes intersect

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh

I am new to Unity and I am trying to find a way to highlight or draw line on where 2 or more meshes intersect.
It is quite hard to demonstrate what I want with words, so if I use pictures,
this is what I have, a cube and parallel planes.
[a cube with 2 planes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYoMm.png)
and this is what I want, line drawn where a cube and planes intersect.
[line drawn on the intersection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FgLa.png)

I tried multiple tutorials on YouTube using shader graph

But all of them only worked with 1 planes, where I need to highlight multiple parallel planes at once. I tried making the planes transparent from opaque, but that ruins everything.

Will you guys help me or share ideas?

Thank you so much

I tried using shader graph from URP, but I maybe too dumb to use it.